# How can I find out if my database is in a stable state?

Tags: sql-server-2008

The field "Tablename" is NULL though it is handled as not null in the case-condition

```
select Name,TableName,
  case when rv.TableName is null
        then rv.Name
        else rv.Name + ' (' + rv.TableName + ')' 
  end as NewName
FROM RV_Type12  rv
where TypeID = 1012
```

This is the output:

```
Name   |TableName|NewName
Nav Bar|NULL     |Nav Bar (NULL)
```

NewName should contain only "Nav Bar" because Tablename is NULL

This test runs correctly:

```
DECLARE @t1 TABLE (
    Name1       varchar(50),
    Name2       varchar(50)
);

INSERT INTO @t1 (Name1, Name2) VALUES('Var1','Value1')
INSERT INTO @t1 (Name1, Name2) VALUES('Var2',NULL)

SELECT Name1,
  CASE WHEN Name2 = '' OR Name2 IS NULL
        THEN Name1
        ELSE Name1 + ' (' + Name2 + ')' 
  END AS Name2
FROM @t1
```

My conclusion is that something is wrong with my database. How can I figure out what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are seeing `NULL`, but that it is the string with that text not the null value.
To be sure, check with select:

```
select * from RV_Type12 where upper(TableName) = 'NULL'
```

To correct that:

```
update RV_Type12 set TableName = null where upper(TableName) = 'NULL'
```

I deduct this, becouse depending of what you have set on CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL you obtain a `null` value for the hole concatenation or an empty string `''` in place where the null was. So you never see NULL in a concatenation

[CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-ar/library/ms176056.aspx)